# Installing drivers on a Windows system using WinPE Preinstallation Environment

Tags: installation, drivers, windows-pe

1. How can I install an INF driver to WinPE 3.0 when it is mounted with DISM?
2. Once WinPE 3.0 is running, how can I install drivers, using their INF, to an *offline* system?

The offline system can be Windows 7, Vista OR XP.

Comment: what os level are you trying to install drivers into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Add and Remove Drivers Offline](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744355.aspx)
[Driver Servicing Command-Line Options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799258.aspx)

1. Assuming you have your driver files extracted to a local folder on the same system you have your WinPE image mounted with dism:
   `dism /image:<image path> /add-driver /driver:<driver path>`
2. Technically, you don't have to inject drivers to an existing Windows 7 installation while offline.  You can do it directly from the OS while it is running.  You just need to change the `/image` argument of dism to `/online` like so:
   `dism /online /add-driver /driver:<driver path>`

I believe Dism is only valid for Win7, WinPE 3, and Server 2008 R2.  I'm not sure what the equivalent utilities are for Vista and XP off hand.

Answer (score 0):

if its windows 7 use DISM to inject new drivers. within the inf comment out the bad ones!

Comment: this does not tell me where to put the files. Or how to use the INF.